# Não redimensionar imagem

Tags: php

Estou enviando para o meu servidor via script php uma imagem com tamanho original de 1000px de largura por 350px de altura mas a mesma está sendo redimensionada para 800px de largura por 280px de altura e gostaria que ela se mantivesse no tamanho original.

Uso a classe WideImage e o meu código está assim:

```
    $arquivo_destino =  $dir_destino . "/" . $nome_arquivo;
copy($arquivo_origem, $arquivo_destino);

// Vamos usar a biblioteca WideImage para o redimensionamento das imagens
require("../lib/WideImage/WideImage.php");

// INSERE A MARCA D'ÁGUA NA FOTO
// $image = WideImage::load($arquivo_destino);
// $marca = WideImage::load("../imagens/logo-marcadagua.png");

//$image->merge($marca, 'right', 'bottom')->saveToFile($arquivo_destino); 

// Carrega a imagem enviada
$original = WideImage::load($arquivo_destino);

// Redimensiona a imagem original para tamanho miniatura
$arquivo_destino = $dir_destino . "/thumb/" . $nome_thumb;
$original->resize(175, 125, 'inside', 'down')->saveToFile($arquivo_destino);
// Redimensiona e salva
```

Para o redimensionamento do thumbs o script funciona perfeitamente.

Comment: Não sei se entendi bem a pergunta mas.. você não poderia apenas salvar em 2 arquivos? um original e outro para thumbs?

Comment: desculpe, não tinha percebido.. poderia editar e mostrar a fonte de $arquivo_origem no código?

Comment: A origem:
$arquivo_origem   = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$dir_destino      = "../banner";
$cleanupTargetDir = true; // Remove arquivos antigos
$maxFileAge       = 5 * 3600; // Temp file age in seconds

Comment: Seu código parece ok, tente isto: `var_dump(getimagesize($arquivo_destino)); die;` após a cópia do arquivo.

Comment: Obrigado @Leonardo Bosquett, estava com limitação de tamanho no envio na hospedagem.

Answer (score 2):

O código está ok, a imagem está sendo redimensionada antes mesmo de chegar ao servidor, 
utilizando este comando você verá o que está sendo enviado ao servidor e assim contornar o problema:

```
var_dump(getimagesize($arquivo_destino)); die;
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda @Leonardo Bosquett.